why in EasyNetQ sendAsync encountred with NullArgumentException in decussate?
I am using EasynetQ to connect two services in the Send/Receive structure. I can receive the first message without any problem but It will be dropped a message in  EasyNetQ_Default_Error_Queue with this content:

"System.ArgumentNullException: routingKey must not be null (Parameter 'routingKey')
at EasyNetQ.Preconditions.CheckNotNull[T](T value, String name)
at EasyNetQ.Preconditions.CheckShortString(String value, String name)
at EasyNetQ.RabbitAdvancedBus.PublishAsync[T](Exchange exchange, String routingKey, Boolean mandatory, IMessage1 message, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at EasyNetQ.DefaultRpc.RespondToMessageAsync[TRequest,TResponse](Func3 responder, IMessage1 requestMessage, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at EasyNetQ.AdvancedBusExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4_01.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at EasyNetQ.RabbitAdvancedBus.<>c__DisplayClass20_1.<b__7>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at EasyNetQ.Consumer.HandlerRunner.InvokeUserMessageHandlerAsync(ConsumerExecutionContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)",

and this pattern will be repeated in the next calls.

Did you provide a Routing key that was not null and not empty?

yes, I found the problem I was registering two types of handlers for same message type in receivers
